# input data from telegram bot in google sheet

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I wanna use spreadsheet via telgeram bot as TODO list in order to when input something in my phone that should be save in spreadsheet.(im coding just like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoTpdxbkGGk
everything is true and google sheet , telegram bot are truly fectched but i dont know why when i input data in telegram bot this isnt save anything in google sheet.

please help me guys

```
var token="<<BOT-TOKEN>>";
var url="https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token ;
var webAppUrl="https://script.google.com/macros/s/<<secret>>/exec";
var spId='<<secret>>';
function getme() {
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getme");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
function getupdates() {
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/getupdates");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
} 

function setwebhook() {
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setwebhook() {
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text" + text);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(m){ 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Heloo" + JSON.stringify(m));
}
function doPost(m){
    var contents = JSON.parse(m.PostData.contents);
GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),"Telegram Bot Update",JSON.stringify(contents,null,4));
  var text = contents.message.text;
  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var name = contents.message.from.first_name + ' ' + contents.message.from.last_name;
  sendText(id, "HI" + name);
SpreadsheetApp.openById(spId).appendRow([new Date(),id,text,contents,name]);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spId).appendRow([1,2,3,4,5]);
}
/*
{  
    "parameter": {},
    "contextPath": "",
    "contentLength": 310,
    "queryString": "",
    "parameters": {},
    "postData": {
        "type": "application/json",
        "length": 310,
        "contents": "{\"update_id\":*,\n\"message\":{\"message_id\":12,\"from\":{\"id\":*,\"is_bot\":false,\"first_name\":\"*\\*\",\"username\":\"*\",\"language_code\":\"fa\"},\"chat\":{\"id\":*,\"first_name\":\"*\\*\",\"username\":\"*\",\"type\":\"private\"},\"date\":1558331571,\"text\":\"salaaaaaaaaaaaaam\"}}",
        "name": "postData"

}
*/
```

expect this save everything that typed by telegram bot and save the data in google sheet rows.but it dosent save data or show them in sheet cells.it shows nothing

Comment: can you mark my answer as the accepted if it helped?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using App script to interact with your spreadsheet is not really flexible and might not be good if you want to scale your application and add more functionalities.

I created a whole project that allows lecturers manage their registers and take attendance from telegram and then update a spreadsheet automatically. I used the official [Google Spreadsheet Api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)  which has great documentation and flexible use compared to App script.

Here is the code to the project on [github](https://github.com/rotimi-best/attendance-bot). You can find the places where I wrote functions for the spreadsheet in [the modules folder](https://github.com/rotimi-best/attendance-bot/tree/master/modules) and then in the [spreadSheetController](https://github.com/rotimi-best/attendance-bot/blob/master/Controllers/spreadSheetController.js). The project is kind of large but I can give a simple work through on how it will fit your use case.

**Basic Requirements:**

1. Use a library for interacting with telegram api instead of making `POST` and `GET` requests yourself. You can use [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) but you can use [other libraries](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) of your choice.
2. Authenticate your google spreadsheet using the api. There is a great [quick start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) from the google team follow the instructions and you should have a programmable spreadsheet. I am assuming you will do it in nodejs.

Once you have these 2 things the project I linked to above would be useful. I hope it helps, if it isn't clear let me know I don't want to paste all the code here (it's quit a lot) but the attendance project should be self explanatory.

Comment: ok.thank you, it seems great .if i have question about it can i ask you directly?

Comment: Sure, will be happy to help. You can find me on twitter @rotimi_best